# Vscode typescript styledcomponent too slow

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, styled-components, tslint

My vscode type-checking be too slow, when I am using styledcomponent

I Have searched this issue several times, but I founds some relative issue on hit-hub.

I tried to read and tried to figure out what is going on !

But because of my poor English,
I couldn’t understand what   happens. And is it on fixing Process or already fixed ?

And is there alternative solution ?

Sorry for ask lazy qustion, but I really couldn’t understand.

My version 
Typescript: 3.7.3
@types/styled-components: 5.1.0

Relative posts

https://amp.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/babzpx/vs_code_issue_with_styledcomponents/

https://amp.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/blbx9g/vscode_tslint_linting_is_very_slow_sometimes_is/

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30663

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solution 1

You should make sure that you are pulling the latest version of `@types/styled-components`  and also any `older versions` should not be present in your project.

---

If you are using `JavaScript`, you may need to clear your automatic typings `cache` to clear the file that caused this from their `cache`. To do this, delete the typings typing cache file listed below and restart `vscode`:

For MAC:

```
Mac: ~/Library/Caches/TypeScript/3.4
```

For WINDOWS:

```
Windows: %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\TypeScript\3.4
```

FOR LINUX:

```
Linux: ~/.cache/typescript/3.4
```

## Solution 2

Downgrade your workspace to use an older version of `typescript` by [following these instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_using-newer-typescript-versions)

Try to install `@types/styled-components@` into your workspace.

See: [DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#34391](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/34391) for more details